# $\int _{k\pi }^{\left(k+1\right)\pi }\:\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How can I solve the following integral?
$\int _{k\pi }^{\left(k+1\right)\pi }\:\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|dx$

Comment: Isn't that just the same as $\int_0^{\pi} \sin(x)\,dx$?

Comment: No, you really don't need to split it up. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $f(x)=\left|\sin(x)\right|$, first show that $f(x+\pi)=f(x)$ for all $x$, then use that to show that for any $u$:

$$\int_{u}^{u+\pi} f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x)\,dx$$

Comment: hmmm, interesting but I don't understand why $\int_{u}^{u+\pi} f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x)\,dx$, u=0 why?

Comment: Think about it a bit more. Given any function and any $a$, with $f(x+a)=f(x)$ for all $x$, $\int_{u}^{u+a} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^a f(x)dx$.

Comment: why is $ \pi \:and\:not\:2\pi $? because f(x+2pi)=f(x)

Comment: That's true, and the above theorem would be true if you replaced $\pi$ with $2\pi$. But here, $f(x)=f(x+\pi)$, too. @Lucas

Answer (score 1):

Define $I(k) = \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \vert \sin(x) \vert dx$. Since $\vert \sin(x) \vert$ is a continuous function, by the first form of fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$I'(k) = \vert \sin((k+1)\pi)\vert - \vert \sin(k\pi)\vert = \vert -\sin(k\pi)\vert - \vert \sin(k\pi)\vert = 0$$
This means $I(k)$ is a constant for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$. We further have $$I(0) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \vert \sin(x) \vert dx = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x) = 2$$
Hence, $I(k) = 2$ for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: why you put I(0) value and not I(1) ? or something else

Comment: @Lucas You can evaluate it at any value it will give you $2$. We show that the function is constant and evaluate the constant by plugging in a fixed value of $k$.

Comment: why you get sin(x) without module? I think we must to split because between pi/2 and pi is negative

Comment: @Lucas $\sin(x)$ is positive on $(0,\pi)$.